# Editor window change the expand and collapse code button size

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to change the size of the + - node buttons for the code expand/collapse on the left margin? (They're way too small)  Pardon me if this is obvious but I've looked all through the Tools/Options menu and searched online to no avail.  Changing font size has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd> key and change the zoom factor (for the font generally) and adjust via the scrollwheel up/down. I see a change in the size of the boxes, but also the size of the fonts as well which I surmise is not the true goal.

*I am on VS2017 but I believe it is the same for VS2015*

[image]

Comment: To get to the size I want the + - button to be, the font size has to be set to *huge*.  Not very appealing.  I appreciate the answer though.